# AVFoundation libAVFAudio.dylib not found arm64 armv7 Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation

i have to use **AVFoundation** framework in my app.

When i compile my app (with this framework in my Project Settings)
i have the followings errors messages:

***file not found /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib for architecture arm64***

***file not found /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib for architecture armv7***

how can i fix it?

Thanks

BR

Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue while trying to compile an old project. It seems that the file "libAVFAudio.dylib" existed on the iPhoneOS7.0 SDK but not on the new one. Fortunately I had a copy of the old XCode.app so I fixed it by copying that file to the new SDK:

```
iMac:~ acalatrava$ sudo cp "/Applications/Xcode_old.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib" "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/"
```

If you don't have the file you may be able to download an old XCode from Developer Center and you should find it there.

I hope this helps!